# Returned value undefined when trying to load via requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to load the AWS JS SDK using requirejs like this:

```
requirejs(["https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"], function (aws) {
    console.log(aws);
  });
```

But the aws variable return is undefined.

Any suggestions as how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: Not a duplicate, but can help you understand your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404315/no-dependencies-defined-when-they-are-loaded-via-absolute-paths

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto thanks for the link, but I still fail to understand what I need to do to get the library to load

Comment: I could not understand it as well, but I lack knowledge about this lib. I would just add the aws sdk in a script tag.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto unfortunately because of the environment I am using I cannot use a script tag, I don't have access to the html, and need a way to load it via js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work like this:

```
requirejs(["https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"], function () {
        console.log("=== SCRIPT LOADED ===")
        console.log(AWS);
      });
```

AWS SDK is not AMD module. After loaded it will be available as a global object.